# Система регистрации через фреймворк

Tags: framework, php, регистрация

Доброго времени суток всем!

Можно ли средствами фреймворков сделать, к примеру, систему регистрации на сайте?
Фреймворк же, по идее создан для облегчения задач, которые используются постоянно. Как говорят еще - не изобретать велосипед.

Так вот, есть ли целая готовая система регистрации во фреймворке? Ну или хотя бы какие-то наработки, чтобы ее написать было проще?

Comment: Надо смотреть на конкретный фреймворк.

Comment: а у какого фреймворка есть самая полная и лучшая документация на русском?

Comment: Я не буду Вам навязывать своего мнения, воспользуйтесь ссылкой на Yii из моего ответа, что Я вам ниже написал. Посмотрите его документацию, как там она описана, существует сайт на русском языке: http://yiiframework.ru, на котором есть много хороших мануалов, в том числе, и с авторизацией :]

Answer (score 2):

Сначала определитесь с фреймворком, а потом начните изучать его документацию. Во всех уважающих себя фреймворках существуют инструменты для работы с сессиями пользователей, а оно подразумевает, как регистрацию, так и аутентификацию с авторизацией. Мне, к примеру, нравится [Yii framework](http://www.yiiframework.com/) из похапэшных :]

Comment: значит есть, но не во всех. Так. уже понятней мне стало.
т.е велосипеды не обязательно изобретать.

Comment: По правде говоря, систему регистрации и авторизации и без фреймворка несложно сделать. Фреймворк лишь систематизирует этот процесс

Answer (score 1):

Для начала я бы посоветовал определиться, что именно вам надо: [framework](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Фреймворк) или [CMS](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BC), затем понять, что такое [сессия и куки](http://www.softtime.ru/bookphp/gl8_1.php), как работает [регистрация пользователя](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=347) и как [авторизоваться на сайте](http://softtime.ru/info/articlephp.php?id_article=34), потом [изучаем MySQL](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysql.php) или же берем любую варезную CMS, 3 минуты читаем документацию и создаем шедевры веба! =))

Answer (score 0):

Для [Codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com/), например, есть библиотека [Ion-Auth](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth) для таких целей.

Answer (score 0):

[FriendsOfSymfony / FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) для Symfony2:

> Обеспечивает управление пользователями для проекта Symfony2. Совместима с Doctrine ORM & ODM и Propel.